# Enable -Woverflowed-literals for custom numeric types

Tags: haskell, warnings, ghc

By default GHC enables [the `-Woverflowed-literals` warning](https://errors.haskell.org/messages/GHC-97441/) to emit a message if a literal's precision is too great for its type:

```
OverflowedLiterals.hs:10:12: warning: [GHC-97441] [-Woverflowed-literals]
    Literal 258 is out of the Word8 range 0..255
   |
10 |     print (258 :: Word8)
   |            ^^^

OverflowedLiterals.hs:15:12: warning: [GHC-97441] [-Woverflowed-literals]
    Literal 9223372036854775817 is out of the Int range -9223372036854775808..9223372036854775807
   |
15 |     print (9223372036854775817 :: Int)
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is there a way to enable this warning for a custom numeric type?

For example, I'd want this code

```hs
data Word4 = Word4 Bool Bool Bool Bool
instance Num Word4 where
  ...

main = print (17 :: Word4)
```

To cause the compiler to complain

```
StackoverflowExample:LINE:COL: warning: [GHC-97441] [-Woverflowed-literals]
    Literal 17 is out of the Word4 range 0..15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, or at least not with `ghc` at the time of writing. The code to check this is located [here <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/5b51b2a24cbe69070a2f34efd93de55d807b836b/compiler/GHC/HsToCore/Match/Literal.hs#L317-L344):

> ```
> warnAboutOverflowedLiterals dflags lit
>  | wopt Opt_WarnOverflowedLiterals dflags
>  , Just (i, tc) <- lit
>  = if
>     -- These only show up via the 'HsOverLit' route
>     | sameUnique tc intTyConName        -> check i tc minInt         maxInt
>     | sameUnique tc wordTyConName       -> check i tc minWord        maxWord
>     | sameUnique tc int8TyConName       -> check i tc (min' @Int8)   (max' @Int8)
>     | sameUnique tc int16TyConName      -> check i tc (min' @Int16)  (max' @Int16)
>     | sameUnique tc int32TyConName      -> check i tc (min' @Int32)  (max' @Int32)
>     | sameUnique tc int64TyConName      -> check i tc (min' @Int64)  (max' @Int64)
>     | sameUnique tc word8TyConName      -> check i tc (min' @Word8)  (max' @Word8)
>     | sameUnique tc word16TyConName     -> check i tc (min' @Word16) (max' @Word16)
>     | sameUnique tc word32TyConName     -> check i tc (min' @Word32) (max' @Word32)
>     | sameUnique tc word64TyConName     -> check i tc (min' @Word64) (max' @Word64)
>     | sameUnique tc naturalTyConName    -> checkPositive i tc
>
>     -- These only show up via the 'HsLit' route
>     | sameUnique tc intPrimTyConName    -> check i tc minInt         maxInt
>     | sameUnique tc wordPrimTyConName   -> check i tc minWord        maxWord
>     | sameUnique tc int8PrimTyConName   -> check i tc (min' @Int8)   (max' @Int8)
>     | sameUnique tc int16PrimTyConName  -> check i tc (min' @Int16)  (max' @Int16)
>     | sameUnique tc int32PrimTyConName  -> check i tc (min' @Int32)  (max' @Int32)
>     | sameUnique tc int64PrimTyConName  -> check i tc (min' @Int64)  (max' @Int64)
>     | sameUnique tc word8PrimTyConName  -> check i tc (min' @Word8)  (max' @Word8)
>     | sameUnique tc word16PrimTyConName -> check i tc (min' @Word16) (max' @Word16)
>     | sameUnique tc word32PrimTyConName -> check i tc (min' @Word32) (max' @Word32)
>     | sameUnique tc word64PrimTyConName -> check i tc (min' @Word64) (max' @Word64)
> ```

It thus hardcodes the different (implicit) data constructors to work with `Int`, `Word`, `Int16`, `Word32`, etc. and thus checks with the corresponding lower and upperbounds.

Strictly speaking, it might perhaps be possible, but currently not implemented. It will likely be a bit complicated to check if we know that the type to which `17` for example is converted, is of a type that is an instance of `Num` and `Bounded`, since it just translates `17` to `fromInteger 17`.